# Ngram model: Good-Turing Smoothing

Tags: nlp, n-gram

I'm currently taking part of [Kaggle's Billion Word Imputation](http://www.kaggle.com/c/billion-word-imputation) competition for an asignment at university. We are working with a simple 3-gram model. The thing is we had no choice but to ignore unigrams which ocurred 1,2,3 times, and bigrams which ocurred once on our training set, in order to save memory. So we forget about the words with frequencies 1,2,3; the bigrams that contained those words AND the bigrams with frequency 1; and also the 3grams that contained any of the previous deleted ngrams.

Now we've come to the point of finding where the missing word should go, and which word it is. The problem here is how do we calculate/estimate the probabilities of each ngram so that when when we find an unseen word or phrase the probability isn't 0? Well, before finding out that we wouldn't be able to handle the whole training set we thought of using Good-Turing Smoothing, which looked quite good and easy to implement.

For Good-Turing Smoothing we need the frequencies of each frequency, and now we don't have ANY  bigram  (w1, w2) with frequency 1, so what should we do? I thought of just storing that number for each w1, so we can use it in the calculations(*). I really don't know if this will make anything better or not...

On the other hand, regardless of the cut we did in our model, what if we had the following:

Freq  c ---> Freq of Freq Nc

1--->456

2--->123

3--->50

5--->23

To estimate the new c, c*, for the words with frequency c=3 we need both N4 and N2, but N4 is 0!!!

(*) so, although we wouldn't have any words w2 with c=1 stored, we would have N1 which is the most important to calculate the probability of unseen words.

Is there any simple way to solve this (specially this last part)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but I ran into a similar problem. This is a problem with Good-Turing smoothing, and is mentioned specifically in Jurafsky's textbook.

I just used the closest count, either above or below. This seemed to produce decent results.